# Totals Collection - Caching Results

Tags: cart, totals, magento-ee

In a project I'm working on I have a requirement to come up with some slightly different total calculations. In short, I am needing to calculate a discount into the subtotal, and display a new total which does show the discount that is being applied to that sub total.

Example:

Cart Item 1: £24.99

Cart Item 2: £4.99

Sub Total (Default) would be: £29.98

Tax: £6.00

This is the figure I am getting in my cart page

What I am trying to achieve is basically that

Pre-Sub Total Discount = £4.99

Sub Total: £24.99

Tax: £4.99

I reviewed this, http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/ and a few other blog posts on the subject of working with Totals.

One of the articles stated that the address items would be cached, which is what I seem to be getting.

I have successfully rewritten the Sub total, extending Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal to my own class. I can see it steps through the collect() and fetch() methods which when I walk through seems to be doing its job correctly.

public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    if ($address->getAddressType() == 'billing') {
        return $this;
    }

```
//parent::collect($address);

/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote */
$quote =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

$items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();


$allowedFree = 0;
$discount = 0;


$address->setTotalQty(0);

// Business Logic here

$baseVirtualAmount = $virtualAmount = 0;

/**
 * Process address items
 */
$items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (/*$this->_initItem($address, $item) && */ $item->getQty() > 0) {
        /**
         * Separatly calculate subtotal only for virtual products
         */
        if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
            $virtualAmount += $item->getRowTotal();
            $baseVirtualAmount += $item->getBaseRowTotal();
        }
        if ($address->getData('address_type') != 'billing') {
            // Business Logic Here 
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->_removeItem($address, $item);
    }
}

// business logic to work out $discount here
// 

$subTotal = $address->getSubtotal();
// $discount = 0;

$address->setBaseVirtualAmount($baseVirtualAmount);
$address->setVirtualAmount($virtualAmount);

$address->setFeeAmount($discount);
$address->setBaseFeeAmount($discount);

//$address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal - $discount);
//$address->setBaseGrandTotal($grandTotal - $discount);

$address->setDiscountAmount($discount);
$address->setBaseDiscountAmount($discount);

//$address->setSubtotal($subTotal - $discount);
//$address->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal-$discount);

$address->setSubtotal(1.99);
$address->setBaseSubtotal(1.99);

$address->setGrandTotal(1.99);
$address->setBaseGrandTotal(1.99);

$address->save();
$this->_setAddress($address);


/**
 * Initialize grand totals
 */
Mage::helper('sales')->checkQuoteAmount($address->getQuote(), $address->getSubtotal());
Mage::helper('sales')->checkQuoteAmount($address->getQuote(), $address->getBaseSubtotal());
return $this;
```

}

I have removed some business logic code - this simply calculates values relevant to the discount and doesnt impact directly to the $address or $this untill the setting of totals. As you can see from the end I currently have hard coded subtotal, basesubtotal, grandtotal and basegrrandtotal to 1.99. This is an effort to work out why it is getting an incorrect value, ie the non discounted original price despite calculating the discount and applying the discount (apparently).

From what I have read, it was suggested that these items are actually cached so when I am retrieving it in the cart it gets the wrong version of the objects instead of the new one, so I should need to in some way clear that object from its cache replacing it with the updated and correctly calculated ones.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?